# I want to capture video and store it on app folder

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

Hi I want to capture video and close it auto after 10 sec, and preview it on livewire blade file and store it on app storage when click submit. where I mistake please see my code.

Livewire blade file code bellow

```
<div>
                <video id="video-preview" width="640" height="480" autoplay muted wire:ignore></video>
                @if (!$capturing)
                    <button wire:click="startCapture" wire:loading.attr="disabled">Start Capture</button>
                @else
                    <button wire:click="stopCapture" wire:loading.attr="disabled">Stop Capture</button>
                @endif
                <button wire:click="submitVideo" wire:loading.attr="disabled">Submit</button>
            </div>

            @if ($video)
                <div>
                    <video id="video-preview-captured" width="640" height="480" controls wire:ignore>
                        <source src="{{ $video }}" type="video/webm">
                    </video>
                </div>
            @endif

<script src="https://cdn.webrtc-experiment.com/RecordRTC.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        var videoElement = document.getElementById('video-preview');
        var videoPreviewElement = document.getElementById('video-preview-captured');
        var recorder;
        var mediaStream;
        var captureTimeout;

        Livewire.on('startCapture', () => {
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                video: true,
                audio: false
            }).then(function (stream) {
                videoElement.srcObject = stream;
                mediaStream = stream;
                recorder = new RecordRTC(stream, {
                    type: 'video'
                });
                recorder.startRecording();

                // Automatically stop capturing after 10 seconds
                captureTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                    Livewire.emit('stopCapture');
                }, 10000);
            });
        });

        Livewire.on('stopCapture', () => {
            clearTimeout(captureTimeout);
            videoElement.srcObject = null;
            recorder.stopRecording(function () {
                var blob = recorder.getBlob();
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    var base64Video = reader.result;
                    Livewire.emit('captureCompleted', base64Video);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
                mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
            });
        });

        Livewire.on('captureCompleted', (base64Video) => {
            var blob = dataURItoBlob(base64Video);
            var videoURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            videoPreviewElement.srcObject = null;
            videoPreviewElement.src = '';
            
            videoPreviewElement.onloadstart = function() {
                videoPreviewElement.src = videoURL;
                videoPreviewElement.style.display = 'block';
            };
        });

        // Function to convert data URI to Blob
        function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
            var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
            var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
            var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
                ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return new Blob([ab], { type: mimeString });
        }

        document.addEventListener('livewire:unload', function () {
            clearTimeout(captureTimeout);
            if (mediaStream) {
                mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Livewire Controller Code bellow

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;
use App\Models\settings;

class LiveVerificationStepOne extends Component
{
    use WithFileUploads;

    public $video;
    public $capturing = false;

    public function startCapture()
    {
        $this->capturing = true;
        $this->emit('startCapture');
    }

    public function stopCapture()
    {
        $this->capturing = false;
        $this->emit('stopCapture');
    }

    public function captureCompleted($base64Video)
    {
        $this->video = $base64Video;
    }

    public function submitVideo()
    {
        // Save the captured video file to the app's public folder
        $filename = 'captured-video-' . time() . '.webm';
        Storage::disk('public')->put($filename, base64_decode($this->video));

        // Perform any additional processing or storage logic here

        $this->video = null;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.live-verification-step-one');
    }
}
```

I no want to use @push because I load the page with refresh. Starting Capture Video is working but when I click on StopCapture then video camera and capturing is off but recored video not preview and I can't store it.